# how to use .then function with parameters in jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

```
//******************Example for multiple ajax success and failure*************//
    function doAjax1(){
        var data="ajax_mode=request1&sample_data1=sample_data1";
        return $.get("ajax.php",data,function(msg){
            //alert(msg);
        });
    }

    function doAjax2(){
        var data="ajax_mode=request2";
        return $.get("ajax.php",data,function(msg){
            //alert(msg);
        });
    }

//success and error cant be used with $.when()
    $.when( doAjax1(), doAjax2() ).then(function(msg){
        alert('alert oncompletion of both ajax'+msg); //Not returns both ajax result 
      console.log( 'I fire once BOTH ajax requests have completed!' );
   }).fail(function(){
      console.log( 'I fire if one or more requests failed.' );
   }).done(function(){
      console.log( 'I fire if one or more requests done.' );
   });
//****************************************************************************//
```

PHP Codes **ajax.php**

```
<?php
if( isset($_REQUEST['ajax_mode']) )
{
    $ajax_mode=trim($_REQUEST['ajax_mode']);
    switch($ajax_mode){

    case 'request1':
    $sample_data1=$_REQUEST['sample_data1'];
    $checking="checking ajax req 1";
    echo $sample_data1;
    break;

    case 'request2':
    $checking="checking ajax req 2";
    echo $checking;
    break;

    }
}
?>
```

**Question:** function doAjax1, doAjax2 returns the value from server.
I am going to use `$.when()` for multiple ajax request

i need to get all ajax return values once all ajax request had done.

i had used `$.when().then(function(msg){alert(msg)})`

Result of alert `sample_data1,success,[object Object]`[Please Explain me why it alerts like this]

My Expected alert result `sample_data1, sample_data2`

Comment: could you not just merge this question to your previous? I mean they are just related, is not?

Comment: Ya its related but i dont like to confuse readers. since they want to get idea faster

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$.when(doAjax1(), doAjax2())
  .then(myFunc, myFailure);
// Execute the function myFunc when both ajax requests are successful, 
// or myFailure if either one has an error.

myFunc = function(a1,  a2){
    /* a1 and a2 are arguments resolved for the 
        doAjax1 and doAjax2 ajax requests, respectively */
   var jqXHR1 = a1[2]; /* arguments are [ "success", statusText, jqXHR ], this explains why you got `sample_data1,success,[object Object]` in your alert */
   alert(jqXHR1.responseText);
}
```

Comment: Note the jqXHR Object was just added  in jquery1.5, otherwise good answer

Comment: @macarthy - Yes, and the OP is definitely on 1.5, otherwise he can't use `$.when()` ;)